# How to Recover corrupt SQL Sever database?

Tags: sql-server

I am running Windows 2000 OS and while using my SQL application a message popped-up, can anyone figure it out, the message is  like that.

> Msg 5172, Level 16, State 15, Line 1

Comment: We need more details .. error log would be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Paul Randal's blog. Is the database suspected?
If it is, try what he recommends, but keep in mind that you should never detach a suspected database, as you might lose it forever

[Creating, detaching, re-attaching, and fixing a SUSPECT database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/)